# With dhcp enabled I don't have internet, when I have dhcp disabled but with the same settings dhcp provide I have internet

Tags: networking, dhcp

So, I have 2 virtual machines (VMware Workstation), one with Windows Server 2019 and another with Windows 10 Pro. On the server, I have DHCP, Active Directory, and DNS installed and configured. The PC client is connected to the domain. But when I try to use DHCP, it has no internet... And when I disable it and use the same settings it provided, the internet seems to work (can ping server and everything on the network!). I don't really know what is going on... I know that I could just use it without DHCP but I want it with DHCP.

Comment: show us `ipconfig /all` from the affected system, both with and without DHCP configured.

Comment: @John just with guests

Comment: Thanks @FrankThomas! I found out that I had a different gateway on the PC client comparing both pictures of the ipconfig /all. Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Different gateway from the server"